# Error when trying to use the class using php

Tags: php, pdf

I found the code from internet which help me to extract pdf files to text.
this is the code that i have used.

```
<?php

// Include Composer autoloader if not already done.
//include 'vendor/autoload.php';

 // Parse pdf file and build necessary objects.
 $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
 $pdf    = $parser->parseFile('document.pdf');

$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;

?>
```

when i use this method to call the relevant class it gives an error on the browser.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Smalot\PdfParser\Parser' not found in D:\workspace_PHP\pdfparser-master\index.php on line 7
```

i am using php version 5.4
if anyone can tell me the reason, it will be great help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: php told you the reason: `not found`. I guess something is not included

Comment: Autoload your classes.

Comment: how can i autoload the class malik?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Smalot **`class`** file  to your PHP file. As we see there is no include on your PHP file.

Include it something like

```
include('/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php');
```

See the [`GitHub`](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/tree/master/src/Smalot/PdfParser) here

Comment: i have added this path.i got this code from this location.but it returns the error.<?php

// Include Composer autoloader if not already done.
//include 'vendor/autoload.php';
include("src/Smalot/PdfParser/Parser.php");  
// Parse pdf file and build necessary objects.
$parser = new Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('document.pdf');
 
$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;
 
?>same issue comes

Comment: how can i autoload ?can you help me on that plzzzz

Comment: Why have you commented  //include 'vendor/autoload.php'; ?

Comment: I USE THIS CLASS FROM https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/tree/master/src/Smalot/PdfParser

I CANNOT FIND THE AUTOLOAD.PHP

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the **smalot PDFparser library** so it could not found the class file for instance..

you find it here..

https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser

Include this in your source directory and that is it!..

Answer (score 0):

PDFParser has been designed on top of composer library.
I invite you to read composer documentation to understand how to generate and use the composer autoloader.
It's really easy to use and really powerful.

Install composer (http://getcomposer.org/) and type

```
composer.phar install
```

In the same folder as the "composer.json" file.
All dependencies will be downloaded into the "vendor" folder.
Once done, a file will be generated named "vendor/autoload.php".

You have just to include it at first in your script.

http://pdfparser.org/documentation